# can't find the reason => php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

may anyone please take the potatos from my eyes?

After several unsuccessful hours to get the following code to work (i didn't get any custom headers displayed on the server)... may someone please tell me why the following code does not work:

```
curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,        

    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
                
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen($fp, 'w'),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,    
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'X-Bearer-Token: 1234567890',
    'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890'),
]);
```

with a small change it is now running - but i would like to understand why:

```
curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,        

    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
                
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen($fp, 'w'),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2, ]);
    
curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [   
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'X-Bearer-Token: 1234567890',
    'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890'),
]);
```

Comment: The user comments on the manual page for `curl_setopt_array` mention several instances in which this function has problems with specific options, looks like CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER might be one of those affected as well.

Comment: Works fine for me on php 8.0 although note I set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` so I can test it on my local. The headers come through for me for both of your snippets, no issues here. But if it's working the second way and not the first, maybe stick to it. Also people these days don't usually reach for curl on php, you might want to use guzzle.

Comment: ok guys. many thanks till now. 
in the meantime i tried a bit further coming to the following issues: changing php version from 7.3 to 8.0 brings an error 500. calling the script with php 7.3 from console works - calling with php 8.0 it crahes with a fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: curl_setopt_array(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /anywhere/.php:21

After deleting this line it works also with only one curl_setopt_array as shown in the first code. 

mark for future notice to use a curl_setopt_array() for each parameter ;-)